# Spring Data Neo4j overwrites attributes

Tags: neo4j, pass-by-reference, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I tried writing a service, having an `update(User)` function using SDN 4.0.0.
The function should look, it there is a User in the database with the same id, and if so, overwrite this user with the new one.

Having a `UserRepository` which extends the `GraphRepository<User>` I wrote the following code:

```
User updateUser(User user){
  if(userRepository.findOne(user.getId())!=null){
    user = userRepository.save(user);
    return user;
  }else{
    //Exception handling here
  }
}
```

I now have the problem, that each user I update stays the way it was in the database because from the moment, the `findOne(id)` is called, all attributes of the user object get overwritten with the user as it is in the database.

I already fixed the problem, by adding an `existsById(Long id)` function in the repository annotated with the Query **"Match (n:User) where ID(n)={0}"**.

However, I'm still interested, why SDN overwrites an object having the same id as an object i tried to get. I'm assuming there a references involved, but i can't really see the advantages of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design, that when you load an entity from the database, it is the most recent version *in the graph*, thus overwriting any unsaved changes.

If you change the order of operations- load first, if it exists, then modify and save- you should be fine.